# Shortcode return is printing a 1 afterward

Tags: plugins, jquery, shortcode, include

```
function build_total_search_method( $atts ) {

    $shorcode_php_function = include( dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/total_search.php" );

    return $shorcode_php_function;

}
add_shortcode( 'total_search', 'build_total_search_method' );
```

I've created a shortcode that returns an included PHP file instead of a string ... however, after the returned statement, there is a `1` printed.

Two questions:

```
1) What is the `1` all about and how do I remove it?

2) Am I doing this properly?
```

Comment: What is in `/includes/total_search.php`?

Comment: Pure HTML, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the result of calling `include`. You want to grab the output of the included file and return than instead. Use [output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) [buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to do that.

```
function build_total_search_method( $atts ) {

    ob_start();
    include( dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/total_search.php" );
    $shorcode_php_function = ob_get_clean();

    return $shorcode_php_function;

}
add_shortcode( 'total_search', 'build_total_search_method' );
```

Comment: Are there any performance hits with this?

Comment: If the included file has no PHP statements, then there is a slight performance benefit to using [Dan's solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82565/24260). If it does have PHP statements, this is how you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you're getting the `1` from your include, meaning your include succeeded. if you want to assign the value to a variable, your included file can only `return` data. example, in `total_search.php`:

```
<?php
$some_var = 'Some content';
return $some_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

`include()` (and the usually-safer [`include_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)) return whether they succeeded or not. You're seeing a `1` because that is the successful return value. Incidentally, it returns `FALSE`, not `0` on failure (no idea why).

To do what you are trying to achieve, @webaware's solution will work, but a less round-about (and more efficient solution for what it looks like you are trying to do would be to use `file_get_contents()` like so:

```
function build_total_search_method( $atts ) {
    return file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/total_search.php" );
}
add_shortcode( 'total_search', 'build_total_search_method' );
```

Note that I also stripped out the extra variable since it was never used and I think it becomes less readable with that extra line.

Comment: `include` doesn't *always* return 1 on success.

Comment: Technically, you're correct, but that is the default behavior. "include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1." (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Dan's solution is correct if the contents of the included .php don't include any PHP statements that need to be executed (and he's right, it's faster). My solution is needed if there are PHP statements, e.g. template tags.

Comment: @webaware: good point!

Comment: @Dan Is `include_once` appropriate here - the shortcode could appear twice?

Comment: @StephenHarris, agreed. Given that the poster seemed very new to PHP, I wanted to include that bit in there for future reference, but for this particular instance it would probably not be appropriate.